# AddThis - description not appear on my facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, addthis

I have a little probleme when i use AddThis. I set all items for facebook share, with HTML meta tag. When I click on the share button, the content in the pop-up is set ok. But after clicking on the share button in the popup, when I look the post on my facebook wall I can't see the description of the publication.

I have tried many things, in particular :

- The facebook tool debuger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) but I think is not a probleme of facebook cache because in the popup the content is ok.
- To set my description content by `addthis:description="My Description"` instead of `<meta name="description" content="My Description">` but is not working

I don't understand why ma description isn't visible on my facebook wall.

Please HELP me.

Comment: UP! Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with open graph tags? If not, trying using

```
<meta property="og:description" content="your description here" />
```

Also you may want to check the og:type meta tag to specify your content type, this could be useful as well

More info:

http://ogp.me/#types

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381222-optimize-facebook-sharing#.U3CmDM1ycpE

Dont forget to clean the Facebook cache using the Facebook debugger tool after set any of meta tag.

Comment: Yes I use the open graph tags. 

And I have set the type tag like this : `<meta property="og:type" content="article" />`

Comment: Have you an another idea?